# Informix SQL - List all fields & tables

Tags: sql, field, informix, isql

Informix iSQL has a command "`info tables;`" that shows all tables.
The syntax for viewing the fields and their respective data types is "`info columns for table;`"

Is there a similar command that shows table.field for all tables and all fields?

Comment: If you need something else, expand or clarify your question.

Comment: Nope, thats exactly what I wanted and from the person I knew would deliver!

Comment: +1 for working with Informix and especially for "LEFFLER!!!! HELP!!!!" :D He's great! :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Using the preferred JOIN notation:

```
SELECT TRIM(t.tabname) || '.' || TRIM(c.colname) AS table_dot_column
  FROM "informix".systables  AS t
  JOIN "informix".syscolumns AS c ON t.tabid = c.tabid
 WHERE t.tabtype = 'T'
   AND t.tabid >= 100
 ORDER BY t.tabname, c.colno;
```

or the old-fashioned join-in-where-clause notation:

```
SELECT TRIM(t.tabname) || '.' || TRIM(c.colname) AS table_dot_column
  FROM "informix".systables AS t, "informix".syscolumns AS c
 WHERE t.tabid = c.tabid
   AND t.tabtype = 'T'
   AND t.tabid >= 100
 ORDER BY t.tabname, c.colno;
```

Assuming you are using a sufficiently recent version of IDS, you can order by columns not cited in the select-list.  If you get complaints, add the ordering columns to the select list.

The join criterion is obvious; the tabtype = 'T' lists only tables, not views, synonyms and other such items listed in systables; the tabid >= 100 only lists tables created explicitly in the database, not the system catalog.

This does not include the type information - if you want that, you have to do a bit more work.  You will find a file `$INFORMIXDIR/etc/xpg4_is.sql` that contains a crude approximation to an old version of the XPG4 (X/Open standard) Information Schema (hence the file name).  In there, there are functions etc to decode type information from `syscolumns.coltype` and `syscolumns.collength` into recognizable strings.  However, I strongly suspect it does not handle DISTINCT types, nor other user-defined types.  I'll be delighted to be proved wrong, but...   If you add the relevant parts of that file to your database, you should then be able to get the type information too.

Also note that all the INFO commands in ISQL and DB-Access are simulated in the front-end, not executed in the IDS server.  Basically, the programs take the request and convert it into a more complex SQL statement.  See the code in the file `sqlinfo.ec` that is part of SQLCMD (available from the [IIUG Software Archive](http://www.iiug.org/software/)) for how my SQLCMD program handles INFO statements. (Note: the INFO output of SQLCMD is formatted differently from the INFO output of ISQL and DB-Access.)

Comment: If you want to know the table name when you already know your column name, you can use the same query with where condition as `c.colname ='COLUMNNAME'`

Answer (score 3):

As Jonathan Leffer's answer mentions, a full handling of column types and column details gets complicated as can be seen in the the [SYSCOLUMNS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_025.htm) documentation.  But if you are looking at database not using more complicated types, this addition to his script will show the basic type and whether NULLs are allowed:

```
SELECT TRIM(t.tabname) || '.' || TRIM(c.colname) AS table_dot_column,
CASE 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=0 THEN 'CHAR' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=1 THEN 'SMALLINT' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=2 THEN 'INTEGER' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=3 THEN 'FLOAT' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=4 THEN 'SMALLFLOAT' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=5 THEN 'DECIMAL' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=6 THEN 'SERIAL' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=7 THEN 'DATE' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=8 THEN 'MONEY' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=9 THEN 'NULL' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=10 THEN 'DATETIME' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=11 THEN 'BYTE' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=12 THEN 'TEXT' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=13 THEN 'VARCHAR' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=14 THEN 'INTERVAL' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=15 THEN 'NCHAR' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=16 THEN 'NVARCHAR' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=17 THEN 'INT8' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=18 THEN 'SERIAL8' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=19 THEN 'SET' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=20 THEN 'MULTISET' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=21 THEN 'LIST' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=22 THEN 'ROW (unnamed)' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=23 THEN 'COLLECTION' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=40 THEN 'LVARCHAR fixed-length opaque types' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=41 THEN 'BLOB, BOOLEAN, CLOB variable-length opaque types' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=43 THEN 'LVARCHAR (client-side only)' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=45 THEN 'BOOLEAN' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=52 THEN 'BIGINT' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=53 THEN 'BIGSERIAL' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=2061 THEN 'IDSSECURITYLABEL'
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=4118 THEN 'ROW (named)' 
  ELSE TO_CHAR(coltype)
END AS Type,
BITAND(coltype,256)=256 AS NotNull
  FROM "informix".systables  AS t
  JOIN "informix".syscolumns AS c ON t.tabid = c.tabid
 WHERE t.tabtype = 'T'
   AND t.tabid >= 100
 ORDER BY t.tabname, c.colno;
```

Answer (score 2):

I did a basic addition to check the primary key column.
Also added column order, datatype lenght.
This gives the base info for ETL generation

```
SELECT TRIM(t.tabname)  AS TableName
,c.colno                AS ColumnOrder
,TRIM(c.colname)        AS ColumnName
,CASE 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=0 THEN 'CHAR' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=1 THEN 'SMALLINT' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=2 THEN 'INTEGER' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=3 THEN 'FLOAT' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=4 THEN 'SMALLFLOAT' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=5 THEN 'DECIMAL' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=6 THEN 'SERIAL' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=7 THEN 'DATE' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=8 THEN 'MONEY' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=9 THEN 'NULL' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=10 THEN 'DATETIME' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=11 THEN 'BYTE' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=12 THEN 'TEXT' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=13 THEN 'VARCHAR' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=14 THEN 'INTERVAL' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=15 THEN 'NCHAR' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=16 THEN 'NVARCHAR' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=17 THEN 'INT8' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=18 THEN 'SERIAL8' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=19 THEN 'SET' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=20 THEN 'MULTISET' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=21 THEN 'LIST' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=22 THEN 'ROW (unnamed)' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=23 THEN 'COLLECTION' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=40 THEN 'LVARCHAR fixed-length opaque types' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=41 THEN 'BLOB, BOOLEAN, CLOB variable-length opaque types' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=43 THEN 'LVARCHAR (client-side only)' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=45 THEN 'BOOLEAN' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=52 THEN 'BIGINT' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=53 THEN 'BIGSERIAL' 
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=2061 THEN 'IDSSECURITYLABEL'
  WHEN MOD(coltype,256)=4118 THEN 'ROW (named)' 
  ELSE TO_CHAR(coltype)
END                     AS Datatype
,c.collength            AS DatatypeLength
,CASE WHEN NVL(
(
    SELECT MAX(i.idxname)
    FROM "informix".sysconstraints cn inner join "informix".sysindexes i 
        on cn.idxname = i.idxname
        and cn.tabid = i.tabid
    where cn.constrtype = 'P'
        AND cn.tabid = t.tabid
        AND
        (c.colno = i.part1
        OR c.colno = i.part2
        OR c.colno = i.part3
        OR c.colno = i.part4
        OR c.colno = i.part5
        OR c.colno = i.part6
        OR c.colno = i.part7
        OR c.colno = i.part8
        OR c.colno = i.part9
        OR c.colno = i.part10
        OR c.colno = i.part11
        OR c.colno = i.part12
        OR c.colno = i.part13
        OR c.colno = i.part14
        OR c.colno = i.part15
        OR c.colno = i.part16
        )
),'') = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END    AS PK
FROM "informix".systables  AS t  JOIN "informix".syscolumns AS c 
    ON t.tabid = c.tabid
WHERE t.tabtype = 'T'
    AND t.tabid >= 100
    --AND t.tabname = 'resource'
ORDER BY t.tabname, c.colno;
```

Comment: Note that the length for DECIMAL, MONEY, DATETIME, and INTERVAL types are encoded intricately.  Even VARCHAR and NVARCHAR are nominally encoded, but it is rare to encounter a column where the minimum length is not zero so the encoding is usually invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Use syscolumns table. Such information is described in [IBM Informix Guide to SQL](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/sqlrmst41.htm)

I have done simple Python utilities that shows schema info for [Informix](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576621/), [Oracle](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576534/) and [PostgreSQL](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576557/). They are useful if you have to compare databases.