# sql query for header info along with data in columns in informix

Tags: sql, informix

I tried many queries  like using this

```
SELECT TABNAME,COLNAME from SYSCAT.COLUMNS where TABNAME='DETAILS'
```

Also used `user_tabs` in place of `SYSCAT.COLUMNS` as well, but it does not work in informix.

Comment: Not sure I understand, are you asking about finding schema information? Table names and column names? [This old post might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380782/informix-sql-list-all-fields-tables)

Comment: what is your expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Informix does not install the Information Schema tables necessary to support your query; indeed it does not use the schema name ('owner' in Informix parlance) of `SYSCAT` when it does have (the very old version of) the Information Schema installed.

There's a file `$INFORMIXDIR/etc/xpg4_is.sql` that you can run for a given database that will install tables `informix.TABLES` and `informix.COLUMNS` but not a table `user_tabs`.