# Informix SQL - List all fields & tables where a user has authorized access to

Tags: informix

[There are Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380782/informix-sql-list-all-fields-table) how to retrieve a full list of Tables

**My problem** is more specific, as I want to retrieve a list of tables a specific user is able to perform a certain operation on (eg Select)

Answer (score 1):

With information from [Informix Doc - SYSTABAUTH](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=tables-systabauth)
I am using the following query

```
SELECT TAB.TABNAME 
FROM 
  SYSTABLES TAB, 
  (
    SELECT TABID 
    FROM SYSTABAUTH 
    WHERE 
      GRANTEE = CURRENT_USER AND 
      UPPER(TABAUTH) LIKE 'S%'
  ) AUTH 
WHERE TAB.TABID = AUTH.TABID
```

By upper-ing the case I cover both options:

- lowercase: grantee is able to perform action
- uppercase: grantee is able to grant action to others

The query checks specifically for select privileges, the Informix Docs specify [further privileges](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=tables-systabauth) as well as [columnar privileges](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/informix-servers/12.10?topic=tables-syscolauth)

Comment: Your query doesn't cover permissions granted to PUBLIC.  It also doesn't cover permissions granted via roles.  And, for a final twist of agony, it doesn't cover column-level permissions, which are relevant for SELECT and UPDATE.  OTOH, I don't think you need worry too much about the column-level permissions in this query.  And you simply need to be aware of the issue with roles.  But ignoring PUBLIC permissions seriously underestimates who can select from the tables.

Comment: @jonathan-leffler Thanks for the info! Do you have a query / method to access all the options? I'll happily accept that answer!